# Django ModelViewSet Method \"DELETE\" not allowed even when providing ID in the URL as required for detail views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, url-pattern

I am using `ModelViewSet` for a `CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser)` model. Every other action is working except `Destroy`.

My viewset:

```
class UserDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'head', 'options', 'trace',]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.all().filter(email = self.request.user)
```

This is my URL:

```
router.register(r'profile', UserDetailView, basename='user_detail')
```

As per the `DefaultRouter()` convention, I'm using this URL:`127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/profile/f7b5bcbe-7c92-494d-a3a2-a07e686b6e63/` with `127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/` as the prefix. The authorization token is in its header. Here, I'm using `UUID` field as the `ID` field.

When I'm calling the URL with `DELETE` method in postman, it's returning:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong here! Generally this message is shown if an `ID` is not provided in the URL for the detail view. But, here I'm providing ID. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the viewset itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was because I did not included `delete` method in the allowed method list.
In the `http_method_names` list I added `delete` and it's now working:

```
http_method_names = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'head', 'options', 'trace', 'delete',]
```

Silly mistake.